# "Страница авторизации" в публичной Wi-Fi сети

Tags: wifi

В публичных Wi-Fi сетях, например в таких как в Московском метро, после подключения к сети "переадресовывает" на определенную страницу, как вообще "это называется"? и если можно, дайте ссылку на разъяснение, как такое реализовать.

P.S. Прошу прощения за мою глупость, и возможно за непонятную формулировку вопроса.

Comment: Называется это [Captive Portal](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Называется это [Captive Portal](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal):

> **Captive portal** — сетевой сервис, требующий от подключившегося к Сети пользователя выполнить некоторые действия для получения доступа в Интернет. Обычно используется для взимания платы, аутентификации абонента либо показа рекламы. Впервые описан специалистами [Стэнфордского университета](/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82) в 1999 году.

Comment: `но что еще здесь можно написать я не знаю, так как все есть по ссылке`, хоть ответ и можно найти по ссылке, но если ссылка протухнет, ответ будет без решения. По этому принято разворачивать полные ответы, а ссылки приводить в качестве источника.